# Why doesn't quartz work?

Tags: java, concurrency, quartz-scheduler

I work with Quartz lib and I have simple code like this:

```
public void run() {
    try {

        SchedulerFactory factory = new StdSchedulerFactory();
        Scheduler scheduler = factory.getScheduler();
        scheduler.start();

        JobDetail job = JobBuilder
                .newJob(HelloWorldJob.class)
                .withIdentity("tJob")
                .build();

        Trigger t = TriggerBuilder
                .newTrigger()
                .withIdentity("tTrigger")
                .startNow()
                .withSchedule(CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute(19, 50).inTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault()))
                .build();


        scheduler.scheduleJob(job, t);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

And Job class:

```
public class HelloWorldJob implements Job {
    @Override
    public void execute(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
        System.out.println("HELLO WORLD");
    }
}
```

19:50 - is a time when i expected to see the result.
But it does not work.
What is wrong with this part of code?

Maybe i forgot something. Please, help me.

P.S. I tried with `.inTimeZone(TimeZone.getDefault())` and without it. And i hade same result in both.

**Holy moly**
Today it's work fine. But i swear, yesterday it didn't work.
Maybe problem in time visualization?
Today i set 11 hour and 52 minutes. And it works fine in 11:52 and write "Hello" to console, but yesterday i have written 19:50 and it did not work.
Should i write in another time system? With A.M/P.M?
Or what the hell?

Comment: The Code within the run method seems to be ok. What is the misfire instruction of `t`? I.e. what says `t.getMisfireInstruction()`. Could you check the next fire time after scheduling the job (`t.getFireTimeAfter(new Date())`)?